# How should the values of a list be scaled such that they meet standard deviation and mean requirements?

Tags: python, list, scale, mean, standard-deviation

I have lists of values that I want to have scaled to meet certain standard deviation and mean requirements. Specifically, I want the datasets standardised to mean 0 with standard deviation 1, except for datasets for which all values are greater than 0; these I want scaled such that their mean is 1.

What would be a good way to do this type of thing in Python?

Comment: I think you're trying to solve a set of equations to meet certain values. You should search for "python goal seek" or "python equation solver".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with data in Python, you're going to want to be using the science stack (see [here](http://www.scipy.org/about.html)), in particular `numpy`, `scipy`, and `pandas`.  What you're looking for is the `zscore`, and that's a common enough operation that it's built-in to `scipy` as [`scipy.stats.zscore`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html).

Starting from a random array with non-zero mean and non-unity stddev:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import scipy.stats
>>> data = np.random.uniform(0, 100, 10**5)
>>> data.mean(), data.std()
(49.950550280158893, 28.910154760235972)
```

We can renormalize:

```
>>> renormed = scipy.stats.zscore(data)
>>> renormed.mean(), renormed.std()
(2.0925483568134951e-16, 1.0)
```

And shift if we want:

```
>>> if (data > 0).all():
...     renormed += 1
...     
>>> renormed.mean(), renormed.std()
(1.0000000000000002, 1.0)
```

We could do this manually, of course:

```
>>> (data - data.mean())/data.std()
array([-0.65558504,  0.24264144, -0.1112242 , ..., -0.40785103,
       -0.52998332,  0.10104563])
```

(Note that by default this uses a delta degrees of freedom of 0, i.e. the denominator is N.  If you want N-1, pass `ddof=1`).